# When finish query left join in hibernate, I want to get all data

Tags: hibernate

File DTO

```
public class UserDto {

    private String userId = "";
    private String userName = "";
    private String birthDay = "";
    private byte[] avatar;
    private String beginDate = "";
    private String userRole = "";
    private String deleteFlg = "";
    private String editFlg = "";
    private Set<ProjectMemberDto> projectMember;
    //Getter  Setter
}
```

Query

```
String sql = "SELECT * " +
        "FROM T_USER LEFT JOIN " +
        "T_PROJECT_MEMBER " +
        "INNER JOIN T_PROJECT " +
        "ON T_PROJECT_MEMBER.PROJECT_ID = T_PROJECT.PROJECT_ID " +
        "ON T_PROJECT_MEMBER.MEMBER_ID = T_USER.USER_ID " +
        "where T_USER.USER_ID like '%a%' " +
        "and T_USER.USER_NAME like '%A%' " +
        "and T_PROJECT.BEGIN_DATE <= '2014/06/25' " +
        "and T_PROJECT.END_DATE >= '2014/06/25' " +
        "ORDER BY T_USER.USER_ID";
        SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery(sql);
        query.addEntity(UserDto.class);
        List<UserDto> listUser = query.list();
        return listUser;
```

When finish query I have a List, but I don't know how to get data UserId, ProjectId, ProjectName .....

Comment: I woudln't do `select *`. The select clause needs to fit the UserDto. By the way: why don't you query using HQL, getting full objects back (that's why we have a ORM, isn't it?) and put it into the DTO with normal C# code?

Answer (score 0):

You have a native query with a DTO projection and this way all the selected data will beone œne hierarchical level.

So Hibernate will do take the query results and populate the DTO on a one to one column to field mapping. It won't populate a collection of ProjectMemberDto but you can do it yourself with the resulted one level data.

To get hierarchies you should fetch the entities instead, assuming you have the mappings in place.

Answer (score 0):

In this line:

```
List<UserDto> listUser = query.list();
```

You have the list of UserDto, you can iterate through your List:

```
for(UserDto user: listUser){
user.getUserId(); //assuming you have proper setter and getter
}
```